# Average number of tiles of a (0,1)-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a (0,1)-matrix $A$, I'll denote by $\mu(A)$ the number of maximal monochromatic polyominoes in $A$ (i.e., the number of connected polyominoes contained in $A$ each of which is either all 0 or all 1 such that each polyomino is as large as possible - so they thus tile $A$).  I do not know of any literature on $\mu(A)$, so I apologize if there is already some notation for the quantity that I am not using.

So for example if $A$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, $\mu(A) = n + 2$.  For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, we have $\mu(A) \leq n^2$, with equality if and only if $A$ is one of the "checkerboard matrices".

I would like to understand what $\mu(A)$ is on average, as we allow the size of the matrix $A$ to tend toward infinity. In particular, is it true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{Average value of $\mu$ over all $n\times n$ (0,1)-matrices}}{n^2} = 1
$$

Comment: For a checkerboard matrix, why don't you get $n^2$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Whoops sorry, you are absolutely correct - I edited it... I was having a dyslexic moment.

Comment: Surely the limit cannot be as large as $1$.
Even for a random $1 \times n$ matrix the corresponding limit
$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\rm E}(\mu) / n$ is only $1/2$
(in fact the expected value is exactly $(n+1)/2$).
In two dimensions, the expected density of monominos is only $1/16 + O(1/n)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit is positive but well below $1$; I show that the limit is in $(0.09448, 0.2646)$, and outline how to approximate it much more closely than this.

The average of $\mu$, call it ${\rm E}(\mu)$,
is twice the average number of maximal all-0 polyominos;
so the limit of ${\rm E}(\mu) / n^2$ is twice the expected number of
maximal all-0 polyominos per unit area of a large square.
That limit is the special case $p=q=1/2$ of
the expected number, call it $\epsilon(p)$,
of maximal all-0 polyominos per unit area
when each entry is independently 0 or 1 with probability $p,q$ respectively
($p+q = 1$).  We can approximate $\epsilon(p)$ by writing it as a sum
$\sum_P \epsilon_P(p)$ over all possible polyomino shapes $P$,
and calculating partial sums over all $P$ of size at most $k$.

The contribution $\epsilon_P(p)$ is $p^{|P|} q^{|\delta(P)|}$,
where $|P|$ is the size of $P$, and $|\delta(P)|$ is the number of
cells at distance $1$ from $P$.  (We do *not* identify different orientations;
for example, for $k=4$ there is one square $P$, two straight ones,
four S/Z shaped tetrominos, four T-shaped, and eight that are L-shaped.)
So we seek $\sum_P p^{|P|} q^{|\delta(P)|}$.  Note that
$\sum_P |P| p^{|P|} q^{|\delta(P)|} = p$ because this is just
the expected number of 0 entries per unit area.

The analysis so far works in any dimension; for example, in dimension $1$
there is a unique $P$ of each size $k \geq 1$, and $|\delta(P)| = 2$ always,
so $\epsilon(p) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k q^2 = p q^2/(1-p) = p q$
(and indeed $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k p^k q^2 = p q^2/(1-p)^2 = p$).
For example, $\epsilon(1/2) = 1/4$, and the expected number of
maximal all-0 or all-1 strings in a random bitstring of length $n$
is asymptotically $2\epsilon(1/2) n = n/2$.
(Exercise [noted in my comment]: in fact that expected number is
exactly $(n+1)/2$.  What happens for arbitrary $p$?)

In dimension $2$, the sum of $\epsilon_P(p)$ over $|P| \leq 4$ is
$$
p q^4 + 2 p^2 q^6 + p^3 (2 q^8 + 4 q^7)
+ p^4 (q^8 + 2 q^{10} + 4 q^8 + 4 q^8 + 8 q^9),
$$
and the sum of $|P| \epsilon_p(P)$ up to $|P| \leq 4$
is obtained from by multiplying the $k$-th term by $k$ ($k=1,2,3,4$),
and comes to $p - 315 p^5 + 1824 p^6 - 4848 p^7 + \cdots$.
(The coefficient $315$ seems to come from the number of rooted 5-ominos,
see https://oeis.org/A048664 .)
For $p=1/2$ these sums are only $387/2^{13}$ and $612/2^{13}$
respectively.  It follows that the $|P| \geq 5$ terms must contribute
$1/2 - 612/2^{13}$ to the sum of $|P| \epsilon_p(P)$,
and thus can contribute at most $1/5$ of that to the sum of $\epsilon_p(P)$.
We conclude that
$$
\frac{387}{2^{13}} < \epsilon(1/2) < 
\frac{387}{2^{13}} + \frac15 \left( \frac12 - \frac{612}{2^{13}} \right)
= \frac{5419}{40960};
$$
numerically these bounds are $0.04724+$ and just under $0.1323$.
Hence the answer to the OP's question is between $0.09448$ and $0.2646$,
as claimed.

Polyominos have been tabulated well beyond $k=4$.
It must be feasible to compute $\sum_{|P| \leq k} \epsilon_P(1/2)$ and
$\sum_{|P| \leq k} |P| \epsilon_P(1/2)$ for $k$ large enough to obtain
a reasonably close approximation to $\epsilon(1/2)$, and thus to
the value $2\epsilon(1/2)$ of the limit that the OP seeks.

Comment: Update: including the 63 forms of the 12 pentominos narrows the interval to
$(3253/2^{15}, 15535/2^{16})$, numerically $(0.09927, 0.23705)$.
[The F,I,L,P,N,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z pentominos have multiplicities
$8,2,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,1,8,4$ and neighborhood sizes
$9,12,11,9,10,10,10,11,9,8,10,10$.]

Answer (score 3):

On the 2004 Putnam, Problem A5, it was essentially asked to show that the value of your limit is greater than 0.125. One way to achieve this which yields better lower bounds than Noam's answer proceeds by coloring one square at a time and is as follows:

First color the top and left edges of a square of side length $n$. This is just the one dimensional case with $2n - 1$ tiles, so the expected number of components in what has been colored so far is $n$. Now color the squares in the interior one at a time, always choosing the topmost and leftmost square, and examine how the expected number of components can change.

If the two already colored squares adjacent to the chosen square are part of different components, the expected change to the number of components is 0. Thus we care only about the probability that the two adjacent squares belong to the same component. This occurs slightly more than $\frac{1}{4}$th of the time, with the most common case being when the two squares have a common neighbor of the same color as them. From this we see that we expect the number of components to increase by slightly more than $\frac{1}{8}$th each time, giving that the expected number of components is greater than $$\frac{(n-1)^2}{8} + n.$$

This yields a lower bound on the limit of $0.125$, which can be strengthened slightly by considering more complicated "loops" which would allow the two squares adjacent to the chosen square to belong to the same component. For example, with probability $\frac{2}{2^8}$ (ignoring concerns about the edge), the two squares will already be joined by a path which walks around the outside of a $3$-by-$3$ square, but not by their common neighbor. This improves the lower bound to $\frac{33}{2^8}$, and its not hard to get better lower bounds by considering longer loops. By using the first eight such loops I could think of (those which can be contained in a 4x4 square), I obtained a lower bound of $\frac{4261}{32768} \approx 0.13$.

Forgive me for this answer which maybe should have been a comment - I did not have enough reputation to just comment a mention of the Putnam problem.